# C# powerups how to continue spawning when to 10 when 1 powerups is collected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, 2d

Now it will only spawn to 10 powerups. when 1 is collected, it doesn't spawn to 10 powerups

```
[SerializeField] public GameObject[] spawnPowerups; 
public int amountOfPowerUpsToSpawn = 10;
[SerializeField] public float PowerupsWaitTime = 1f;

IEnumerator SpawnPowerUpsCoroutine()
    {
        for (int i = amountOfPowerUpsToSpawn; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -3);
            int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
            Instantiate(spawnPowerups[Random.Range(0, spawnPowerups.Length)], spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(PowerupsWaitTime);
        }
        
    }    

void Start()
    {
     
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPowerUpsCoroutine());
    }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the script you sent.

```
IEnumerator SpawnPowerup()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(PowerupsWaitTime);
    int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -3);
    int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
    Instantiate(spawnPowerups[Random.Range(0, spawnPowerups.Length)], spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);        
}
```

and call this from your Collecting Powerup script

```
YourPowerupGameobject.GetComponent<YourComponent>().SpawnPowerup();
```

Comment: yes it will spawn 10 powerups, but if 1 is collected there will be 9 powerups and I want it to spawn back to 10 powerups

Comment: Then you should show your Collect Powerup script. Do you want your powerups to be created immediately after a powerup collected?

Comment: having a PowerupsWaitTime after is collected

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is what you want to achieve. I made some changes and replaced the for with a while loop. Also added something to test the powerup collection to trigger the spawner on pickup. Tis code below.

PowerUpSpawner.cs

```
[SerializeField] public GameObject[] spawnPowerups;
public int amountOfPowerUpsToSpawn = 10;
public int PowerupsWaitTime = 1;
private int currentPowerUps = 0;

private Coroutine _coroutine;

public void PickedUpPowerUp()
{
    currentPowerUps--;
    //Check if Coroutine is null
    if(_coroutine is null)
    {
        _coroutine = StartCoroutine(SpawnPowerUpsCoroutine());
    }

}

IEnumerator SpawnPowerUpsCoroutine()
{
    while (currentPowerUps < amountOfPowerUpsToSpawn)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(PowerupsWaitTime);
        int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-5, 5);
        int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(spawnPowerups[Random.Range(0, spawnPowerups.Length)], spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        //Set parent to get the spawner
        clone.transform.SetParent(transform, false);

        //Increment powerups counter
        currentPowerUps++;
    }
    //Set coroutine to null
    _coroutine = null;

}

void Start()
{
    _coroutine = StartCoroutine(SpawnPowerUpsCoroutine());
}
```

PowerUp.cs

```
private PowerUpSpawner powerUpSpawner;

private void Start()
{
  powerUpSpawner = GetComponentInParent<PowerUpSpawner>();
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    powerUpSpawner.PickedUpPowerUp();
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

[image: Example]